# Delete portions of a text file with Python

Tags: python

I have a large .txt file (best part of 900,000 lines) with just one item, a postcode, on each line. I've got the following code to use it as a list, and to then select an item randomly and print it.

```
import random

postcodes = open("postcodes.txt", "r")
content_list = postcodes.readlines()
your_code = random.choice(content_list)

print(f"your code is {your_code}")
```

This is working great, but I absolutely do not need all of those postcodes (or want to handle this massive file) for this project, and I would like to use Python to write a new .txt file with a good chunk of the postcodes gone.  Obviously I really don't want to manually go through and delete half of each alphabetized section (the postcodes in the txt file are listed alphabetically from A-Z), I'd love to be able to to delete a chunk from the As, Bs, Cs  etc until it looks balanced and write to a new file.

Even better, if there's a way to cut each alphabetical 'group' to a chosen, consistent-throughout number of lines while cutting the rest, and writing that to a new file, that would be awesome.

I'm very very new to python so if there's a simple, beginner-friendly solution to this I'd be thrilled.  Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Google sorting, itertools.groupby, random.sample then post back here if you cannot get it to work.

Comment: There are easy ways to slice your text file automatically using python, but it's a bit unclear  exactly how you want to divide your data. Once you know that it is straightforward to do

Comment: Thank you both! Sorry that i wasn't clear enough.  Ok, so currently there are many thousands of postcodes and they are alphabetically organised.  So theres around 25k that begin with A, 30k that begin with B, etc.  What I'd like to do, ideally, is cut the data so there are 100 that begin with A, 100 that begin with B, etc - so there's an even number of each.  Does that make sense?

I've just tried random.sample to grab 200 of the postcodes and write them to a new file, which is ace, but ideally I'd like to have an even proportion based on the letter they start with.